# Azure Stream Analytics to Event Hub batching not putting events in a list

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I currently have a ASA Job that is streaming to an eventhub. From what I understand it may combine events from my query into batches for throughput reasons. However, when I check my output eventhub using service bus explorer, my events are not kept in a list like this:

```
[
  {
    "Payload": "test1"
  },
  {
    "Payload": "test2"
  }
]
```

and instead show up as

```
{"Payload": "test1"}
{"Payload": "test2"}
```

I am trying to create parity with an old system that seems to need the batched events to come in a list. Is there a way to specify this through options or my queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is `Format` in the [EH output configration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/event-hubs-output#output-configuration). You should switch it from line separated to array.

Pasting the doc here:

> **Format** : Applicable only for JSON serialization. Line separated specifies that the output is formatted by having each JSON object separated by a new line. If you select Line separated, the JSON is read one object at a time. The whole content by itself would not be a valid JSON. Array specifies that the output is formatted as an array of JSON objects.

This is line separated:

```
{"Payload": "test1"}
{"Payload": "test2"}
```

This is array:

```
[
  {
    "Payload": "test1"
  },
  {
    "Payload": "test2"
  }
]
```